# Both leftbar + oframed style

Tags: rules, framed

My requirement is follow:

[image]

and still now I tried is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,framed}

\begin{document}

\begin{leftbar}\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\begin{oframed}
\noindent{{\bf Estimate: The Boltzmann Law for Levitation}\\
As a first example which is instructive both in the context of how to use
the Boltzmann distribution and in telling us how to think about the energy
scale $k_BT$, we consider
 the probability of levitating, by commenting
quantitatively on the probability
that a mass $m$ will levitate to a height $h$.
\index{levitation!and Boltzmann distribution}
 Specifically, recall that the gravitational potential energy of a mass $m$ near the surface of the earth is
$PE=mgh$.  If we recall the Boltzmann law in the form of equation~\ref{eqn:BoltzmannLaw}
and take as our zero of potential energy the surface of the earth itself, we can compute the probability of an object such as a human or a bacterium levitating to a height
$h$ as
\def\theequation{2.9}
\begin{equation}
p(h)=p(0)e^{-mgh/k_BT},
\label{eqn:LevitationEquation}
\end{equation}
\index{Boltzmann distribution!and levitation}
\index{levitation!Boltzmann distribution and}

\noindent
as shown in Figure~\ref{fig:Levitation}.
This equation jibes with our intuition
about the drop-off
of atmospheric pressure with height, a phenomenon seen easily on any
sports watch which reports changes in height with 5 m resolution.  Effectively,
the altimeter on such a watch is nothing more than a Boltzmann meter,
reporting on precisely the same quantity as computed
in equation~\ref{eqn:LevitationEquation} but instead of using
a mass of 100~kg as for a human, using $5 \times 10^{-26}$~kg
for the typical mass of molecules
 in the atmosphere.  Ultimately, it is the dimensionless ratio $mgh/k_BT$ that tells us
 whether levitation is likely or not.  For cases in which this dimensionless number is much
 greater than 1, the likelihood of levitation is negligible.  By way of contrast,
 when this dimensionless number is much smaller than 1, levitation is inevitable.}
\end{oframed}
\end{leftbar}
\end{document}
```

Any better option available? please suggest...

Comment: You shouldn't use `\bf`, instead use `\bfseries` or, if you want a macro taking an argument, `\textbf`.

Comment: Thanks, will take care for the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `tcolorbox` and Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\definecolor{estimateframe}{HTML}{F4DEA9}
\definecolor{estimatetext}{HTML}{898989}

\newtcolorbox{estimate}[1][]
  {%
    ,check odd page
    ,toggle enlargement
    ,colframe=estimateframe
    ,colback=white
    ,right skip=23pt
    ,boxrule=3pt
    ,enhanced
    ,sharp corners
    ,overlay unbroken and first =
      {%
        \tcbifoddpage
          {%
            \filldraw[estimateframe]
              ([xshift=3pt]frame.north east) rectangle
              ([xshift=23pt]frame.south east)
              ;
            \node[rotate=90,font=\sffamily\Large\color{estimatetext}]
              at ([xshift=13pt,yshift=-2cm]frame.north east)
              {\MakeUppercase{estimate}};
          }%
          {%
            \filldraw[estimateframe]
              ([xshift=-3pt]frame.north west) rectangle
              ([xshift=-23pt]frame.south west)
              ;
            \node[rotate=90,font=\sffamily\Large\color{estimatetext}]
              at ([xshift=-13pt,yshift=-2cm]frame.north west)
              {\MakeUppercase{estimate}};
          }%
      }
    ,overlay middle and last =
      {%
        \tcbifoddpage
          {%
            \filldraw[estimateframe]
              ([xshift=3pt]frame.north east) rectangle
              ([xshift=23pt]frame.south east)
              ;
          }%
          {%
            \filldraw[estimateframe]
              ([xshift=-3pt]frame.north west) rectangle
              ([xshift=-23pt]frame.south west)
              ;
          }%
      }
    ,#1%
  }

\usepackage{duckuments} % dummy content

\begin{document}

\blindduck[1-3]

\begin{estimate}[breakable]
\textbf{Estimate: The Boltzmann Law for Levitation}\\
As a first example which is instructive both in the context of how to use
the Boltzmann distribution and in telling us how to think about the energy
scale $k_BT$, we consider
 the probability of levitating, by commenting
quantitatively on the probability
that a mass $m$ will levitate to a height $h$.
\index{levitation!and Boltzmann distribution}
 Specifically, recall that the gravitational potential energy of a mass $m$ near the surface of the earth is
$PE=mgh$.  If we recall the Boltzmann law in the form of equation~\ref{eqn:BoltzmannLaw}
and take as our zero of potential energy the surface of the earth itself, we can compute the probability of an object such as a human or a bacterium levitating to a height
$h$ as
\def\theequation{2.9}
\begin{equation}
p(h)=p(0)e^{-mgh/k_BT},
\label{eqn:LevitationEquation}
\end{equation}
\index{Boltzmann distribution!and levitation}
\index{levitation!Boltzmann distribution and}

\noindent
as shown in Figure~\ref{fig:Levitation}.
This equation jibes with our intuition
about the drop-off
of atmospheric pressure with height, a phenomenon seen easily on any
sports watch which reports changes in height with 5 m resolution.  Effectively,
the altimeter on such a watch is nothing more than a Boltzmann meter,
reporting on precisely the same quantity as computed
in equation~\ref{eqn:LevitationEquation} but instead of using
a mass of 100~kg as for a human, using $5 \times 10^{-26}$~kg
for the typical mass of molecules
 in the atmosphere.  Ultimately, it is the dimensionless ratio $mgh/k_BT$ that tells us
 whether levitation is likely or not.  For cases in which this dimensionless number is much
 greater than 1, the likelihood of levitation is negligible.  By way of contrast,
 when this dimensionless number is much smaller than 1, levitation is inevitable.
\end{estimate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Note that this is just a quick mock-up, I intend to further improve it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...Sorry both the boxes should go page to page in the same manner, but the title `Estimate` should come only on the `first page`, following page that panel should come, also `even page panel should come of left side`, and the `odd page panel should come on right side`...

Comment: @MadyYuvi which wasn't stated in your question. Also, this is page breakable, just load `\tcbuselibrary{breakable}` and specify the `breakable` key.

Comment: @MadyYuvi what should happen if the available space is not sufficient for the "ESTIMATE" label?

Comment: Agreed that I didn't mention in my post... Just now, I've added per your suggestion, it works, is this possible to fix the `odd and even page issue` what I mentioned in my `earlier comment`...

Comment: @MadyYuvi I already fixed that (but didn't edit the answer just yet), still what should happen if the available space on the first page isn't large enough for the "ESTIMATE" in the margin?

Comment: Just now got confirmation that there should be enough space for the text `Estimate` for all occurrence...

Comment: @MadyYuvi so if there isn't the user is at fault and I don't have to detect that?

Comment: Till now, yes, you'r correct...and your suggestion works in a great manner...Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}

\definecolor{warning}{RGB}{255,231,231}
\definecolor{warnline}{RGB}{155,231,231}
\definecolor{estbg}{RGB}{255, 232, 186}
% Definition for Warning Boxes                     
\newmdenv[
  skipabove=10pt,
  skipbelow=10pt,
  innermargin=-51pt,
  outermargin=19pt,
  backgroundcolor=white,
  innertopmargin=15pt,
  innerbottommargin=15pt,
  innerleftmargin=15pt,
  middlelinewidth=0pt,
  everyline=true,
  linecolor=estbg,
  linewidth=4pt,
  font=\normalfont\normalsize,
  frametitlefont=\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries,
  frametitleaboveskip=1em,
  singleextra={
    \draw[estbg,line width=28pt] ($(O)+(-20pt,-2pt)$) -- ($(O|-P)+(-20pt,-\mdfframetitleboxtotalheight)+(0,2pt)$);
    \node[inner sep=0pt,color=black]at ($(O|-P)+(-20pt,-60pt)$) {\rotatebox{90}{\Large\textsf{\textcolor{black!50}{ESTIMATE}}}};     
  }
]{estimate}                     

\begin{document}

\begin{estimate}
{\bf Estimate: The Boltzmann Law for Levitation}\\
As a first example which is instructive both in the context of how to use
the Boltzmann distribution and in telling us how to think about the energy
scale $k_BT$, we consider
 the probability of levitating, by commenting
quantitatively on the probability
that a mass $m$ will levitate to a height $h$.
\index{levitation!and Boltzmann distribution}
 Specifically, recall that the gravitational potential energy of a mass $m$ near the surface of the earth is
$PE=mgh$.  If we recall the Boltzmann law in the form of equation~\ref{eqn:BoltzmannLaw}
and take as our zero of potential energy the surface of the earth itself, we can compute the probability of an object such as a human or a bacterium levitating to a height
$h$ as
\def\theequation{2.9}
\begin{equation}
p(h)=p(0)e^{-mgh/k_BT},
\label{eqn:LevitationEquation}
\end{equation}
\index{Boltzmann distribution!and levitation}
\index{levitation!Boltzmann distribution and}

\noindent
as shown in Figure~\ref{fig:Levitation}.
This equation jibes with our intuition
about the drop-off
of atmospheric pressure with height, a phenomenon seen easily on any
sports watch which reports changes in height with 5 m resolution.  Effectively,
the altimeter on such a watch is nothing more than a Boltzmann meter,
reporting on precisely the same quantity as computed
in equation~\ref{eqn:LevitationEquation} but instead of using
a mass of 100~kg as for a human, using $5 \times 10^{-26}$~kg
for the typical mass of molecules
 in the atmosphere.  Ultimately, it is the dimensionless ratio $mgh/k_BT$ that tells us
 whether levitation is likely or not.  For cases in which this dimensionless number is much
 greater than 1, the likelihood of levitation is negligible.  By way of contrast,
 when this dimensionless number is much smaller than 1, levitation is inevitable.
\end{estimate}


\end{document}
```

This may not be quite right on alternate pages, since you are using the book class (which will assume everything is two-sided).

[image: Mock up of 'estimate' box]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...Sorry both the boxes should go page to page in the same manner, but the title `Estimate` should come only on the first page, following page that `panel` should come, also even page panel should come of `left side`, and the `odd page` panel should come on `right side`